# sending an order through BTC-e API incorrect field error

Tags: api

I get the following message when trying to send a buy/sell order through btc-e api using a variable:
`"you incorrectly entered one of the fields"`.

This is the line of code I use for sending an order:

```
APIMain.Trade(BtcePair.BtcUsd, TradeType.Sell, Math.Round(myAskP, 4), Math.Round(myAskQ, 4));
```

Sending an order via api does work when I enter it like this:

```
APIMain.Trade(BtcePair.BtcUsd, TradeType.Sell, 800m, 0.5m);
```

How do I force a decimal variable to be formatted like the line above?
Anybody experienced similar problems?

Comment: might be helpful if you could mention the particular programming language you are using I'm guessing maybe Java?

Answer (score 2):

The exact problem you're facing regards the number of acceptable decimal digits in the `rate` field.

You're trying to submit an order on the `BTC/USD` pair, which happens to have a max decimal allotment of 3. Meaning, you can submit an order for example 800.123, but NOT 800.1234 Not all pairs are the same. `LTC/USD` can have 6 digits, most BTC based pairs can accept 5 digits.

To get a list of exact information regarding the individual pairs, use this public endpoint for a JSON object that gives you all the values:  https://btc-e.com/api/3/info

As far as I know, all pairs' `amount` fields can have a max of 8 decimals. You are rounding both the amount and rate to 4 digits. Fix the rate field and it should work.

Please keep in mind when I say "decimal places" I mean actual number of digits after the period in a number. Not the numerical type `decimal` that you are using. Using a `double` or `float` will work as well, provided they are rounded properly.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be in the Price. This worked:

APIMain.Trade(BtcePair.BtcUsd, TradeType.Buy, decimal.Floor(myBidP),decimal.Round(myBidQ,4));

Can somebody confirm that the price must be rounded to the nearest integer?

Bonne chance trading everybody......

Comment: Price and quantity are automatically rounded by BTC-e. I believe they round to the nearest number (e.g. 0.5 up 0.4999 down), still I would strongly recommend rounding down yourself to avoid missing trades due to insufficient funds.